# Why does DDEV keep downloading docker-compose-linux?

Tags: ddev

Over the course of a day, my DDEV will download docker-compose many times. (20?) Randomly asking for different versions.

```
Downloading https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.21.0/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
Downloading https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.23.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
```

I've tried adding required_docker_compose_version: "v2.21.0" (and required_docker_compose_version: "v2.23.3") to my global configuration, but it appears to have no effect.

Is this appropriate behavior for DDEV?
Or is there something I can configure to reduce the number of downloads?

Definitly not a show stopper. Everything else is running super-smooth.

Comment: This was also reported in DDEV Discord, https://discord.com/channels/664580571770388500/1188878616478629898, and the outcome seemed to have been something about PhpStorm's terminal, but it wasn't a clear outcome. That was also a linux machine. If @stasadev's answer below doesn't help you, I'll be happy to do a live screenshare with you to try to sort it out. It's very odd. Please read the thread in Discord as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal behavior.

1. Check if you have another old `ddev` on your Linux and remove it:

   ```bash
   # should return only one path, for example, /usr/bin/ddev
   which -a ddev
   ```
2. Rename the global configuration file to see if any settings are interfering. Rename it back after testing:

   ```bash
   mv ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml.bak
   # try different ddev commands
   ddev version
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt suggestions. There was a second ddev. I removed it, there was a single download, and now all is quiet.